# Trouble with Transparent Background in scene created with Three.js Editor

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency

I'm having a bit of trouble setting the background of a three.js scene to be transparent. This scene was created with the editor (which is really snazzy, by the way), and exported.

I've set alpha: `true` on the WebGLRenderer and I've added the alpha value at the end of the `setClearColor` call, but still, no transparency.

I've tried setting the `scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000,0)`, but Color doesn't work with alpha as I expected and this seems to be read as a 2 of three parts of an rgb style color declaration.

Is there something I'm missing? Should I not use the Editor to create a scene?

Here is the full app.js code as exported by the editor and tweaked by me:

```
/**
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com/
 */

var APP = {

Player: function () {

    var scope = this;

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    var controls, effect, cameraVR, isVR;

    var events = {};

    this.dom = document.createElement( 'div' );

    this.width = 500;
    this.height = 500;

    this.load = function ( json ) {

        isVR = json.project.vr;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true,
        } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

        if ( json.project.gammaInput ) renderer.gammaInput = true;
        if ( json.project.gammaOutput ) renderer.gammaOutput = true;

        if ( json.project.shadows ) {

            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            // renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

        }

        this.dom.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        this.setScene( loader.parse( json.scene ) );

        this.setCamera( loader.parse( json.camera ) );

        events = {
            init: [],
            start: [],
            stop: [],
            keydown: [],
            keyup: [],
            mousedown: [],
            mouseup: [],
            mousemove: [],
            touchstart: [],
            touchend: [],
            touchmove: [],
            update: []
        };

        var scriptWrapParams = 'player,renderer,scene,camera';
        var scriptWrapResultObj = {};

        for ( var eventKey in events ) {

            scriptWrapParams += ',' + eventKey;
            scriptWrapResultObj[ eventKey ] = eventKey;

        }

        var scriptWrapResult = JSON.stringify( scriptWrapResultObj ).replace( /\"/g, '' );

        for ( var uuid in json.scripts ) {

            var object = scene.getObjectByProperty( 'uuid', uuid, true );

            if ( object === undefined ) {

                console.warn( 'APP.Player: Script without object.', uuid );
                continue;

            }

            var scripts = json.scripts[ uuid ];

            for ( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i ++ ) {

                var script = scripts[ i ];

                var functions = ( new Function( scriptWrapParams, script.source + '\nreturn ' + scriptWrapResult + ';' ).bind( object ) )( this, renderer, scene, camera );

                for ( var name in functions ) {

                    if ( functions[ name ] === undefined ) continue;

                    if ( events[ name ] === undefined ) {

                        console.warn( 'APP.Player: Event type not supported (', name, ')' );
                        continue;

                    }

                    events[ name ].push( functions[ name ].bind( object ) );

                }

            }

        }

        dispatch( events.init, arguments );

    };

    this.setCamera = function ( value ) {

        camera = value;
        camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        if ( isVR === true ) {

            cameraVR = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
            cameraVR.projectionMatrix = camera.projectionMatrix;
            camera.add( cameraVR );

            controls = new THREE.VRControls( cameraVR );
            effect = new THREE.VREffect( renderer );

            if ( WEBVR.isAvailable() === true ) {

                this.dom.appendChild( WEBVR.getButton( effect ) );

            }

            if ( WEBVR.isLatestAvailable() === false ) {

                this.dom.appendChild( WEBVR.getMessage() );

            }

        }

    };

    this.setScene = function ( value ) {

        scene = value;
        // scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000); // Color can't be alpha? boo. 

    };

    this.setSize = function ( width, height ) {

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        if ( camera ) {

            camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }

        if ( renderer ) {

            renderer.setSize( width, height );

        }

    };

    function dispatch( array, event ) {

        for ( var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

            array[ i ]( event );

        }

    }

    var prevTime, request;

    function animate( time ) {

        request = requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        try {

            dispatch( events.update, { time: time, delta: time - prevTime } );

        } catch ( e ) {

            console.error( ( e.message || e ), ( e.stack || "" ) );

        }

        if ( isVR === true ) {

            camera.updateMatrixWorld();

            controls.update();
            effect.render( scene, cameraVR );

        } else {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

        prevTime = time;

    }

    this.play = function () {

        document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown );
        document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp );
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp );
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove );

        dispatch( events.start, arguments );

        request = requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        prevTime = performance.now();

    };

    this.stop = function () {

        document.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown );
        document.removeEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove );
        document.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart );
        document.removeEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd );
        document.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove );

        dispatch( events.stop, arguments );

        cancelAnimationFrame( request );

    };

    this.dispose = function () {

        while ( this.dom.children.length ) {

            this.dom.removeChild( this.dom.firstChild );

        }

        renderer.dispose();

        camera = undefined;
        scene = undefined;
        renderer = undefined;

    };

    //

    function onDocumentKeyDown( event ) {

        dispatch( events.keydown, event );

    }

    function onDocumentKeyUp( event ) {

        dispatch( events.keyup, event );

    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

        dispatch( events.mousedown, event );

    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

        dispatch( events.mouseup, event );

    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

        dispatch( events.mousemove, event );

    }

    function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

        dispatch( events.touchstart, event );

    }

    function onDocumentTouchEnd( event ) {

        dispatch( events.touchend, event );

    }

    function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

        dispatch( events.touchmove, event );
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Try removing the line `renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );`

Comment: Hello, Andy! 
I tried removing that line, but the background is still appears to be opaque. 
I thought that line was there to set the default background to be black and then fully transparent. 
I even re-exported the scene from the editor with the background color set to black so that it would match this color set to be the clear color. (though that is due to my very vague understanding of what's actually going on)

Comment: Just to check an assumption - how do you know the rendered viewport isn't transparent? What are you seeing instead of transparency? Is it possible whatever is "behind" the canvas is just a solid color and you're seeing that?

Comment: I've set the background on the body element to be #fff, so it should show up as that color.

As a test, in the chrome developer tools, I've set the containing div with a background-color: red, and the canvas itself to have a background-color: green, just in case either of those might have a solid background color.

It seems none of those colors show through the black that is being rendered inside the scene. Usually, on load, you can see a flash of white before the black background and the scene contents are loaded.